# Prevent Android upgrade from breaking app

Tags: android

I am about to hand over a finished Android app to a company, but we're concerned that future Android updates may cause features to become deprecated and no longer work. Is this something to be concerned about, or will deprecated features still work for released versions? If not, is there a way to sandbox the application to keep it as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this something to be concerned about

Yes.

> or will deprecated features still work for released versions?

For a little while. How long "a little while" is depends completely on Google. It might be a decade or might be the next release.

> If not, is there a way to sandbox the application to keep it as is?

No. New phones will come with new versions of Android. If this breaks your app, your app will need to be updated.

You might want to discuss this with the company you wrote the app for and offer to sell them them a long term support contract. They might not understand that an app that works perfectly today might simply stop working even though it hasn't changed.

Answer (score 3):

When Android deprecates an API, it usually leaves it in for at least a couple releases before first removing all function and then finally removing the method altogether. There are certain APIs that have been deprecated since API 21 and still exist in 28.

Android also will allow certain deprecated APIs to continue functioning depending on which API your app targets. For instance, with Android Marshmallow, Android severely limited access to writing to Settings.System. However, apps targeting API 22 or lower can still write without restriction with the proper permissions.

If Google decides that a certain API will no longer function in, say, Q, there's absolutely nothing you can do about it. They may allow apps targeting API 28 (Pie) and lower to still use that API, but there's no guarantee. The only way to avoid removals without updating the app is to not update the Android version.

That brings me to the main issue as I see it. It sounds an awful lot like the company has zero plans to contract you to keep this app maintained. If that's true, then it's not your responsibility. If they are worried about what you described in your question, tell them they'll need to keep you or hire another developer to maintain the app and keep it working on future versions of Android. If they won't do that, then that's their own fault.

TL;DR, you can't work around removals or future-proof your app indefinitely. You can only update it to keep up with Android.